# Junit cucumber retry fail scenario : mvn command I used: "test -e -X -U "-Dcucumber.options=--tags ${tag1}". It is not invoking re-try scenatio

Tags: junit, maven-3, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am using 2 runner file. One for running test and creating failed entry in a text file under target. The second runner class is being called and which runs the failed scenarios again.

When the job is getting triggered using maven command - "test -e -X -U "-Dcucumber.options=--tags ${tag1}", first runner is being called, but not calling 2nd runner class for failed ones.

1. In the POM file I am using "org.apache.maven.plugins" dependency and using

   4.0.0
   CucumberJava
   Automation
   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

   ```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber6-adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mkolisnyk/cucumber-runner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TestRunner*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   ```
2. First Sample Runner (TestRunner.java)

   package Steps;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
   import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
   @CucumberOptions(
   features = "C:\Bhaskar\Workspace_Cucumber\Automation\src\test\resources\Features"
   ,glue = {"Steps"}
   ,plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", "rerun:target/rerun.txt"}
   ,monochrome = true
   //,publish = true
   )
   public class TestRunner {

   }
3. Rerun Runner Sample (TestRunner2.java)

   package Steps;

   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
   import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
   @CucumberOptions(
   features = {"@target/rerun.txt"}
   ,plugin = {"pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", "rerun:target/rerun.txt"}
   ,glue = {"Steps"}
   ,monochrome = true
   //,publish = true
   )
   public class TestRunner2 {

   }

I want to achieve retry fail scenario running with maven command from command line with "-Dcucumber.options".

Comment: You can try using [`courgette-jvm`](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm) , which automatically rerun failed scenarios